# Multiple people using a VBA userform on a common Database

Tags: excel, vba

So, my requirements need me to distribute a VBA userform excel file to different people in my organization, and a single database file which will be kept in a network drive (or any other shared location).
I have tested it and it works fine. To save the entry, it downloads the database from network location, saves the inputs from userform and then closes back the file.
My only concern is that what if multiple people are filling the userform at the same time and pressing the submit button. Will all the information get recorded on database or some entries might get lost?

Please guide me on this, and suggest me any thing that needs to be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Workbook.ReadOnly Properrty

```
 Dim dBook As Workbook, daWas As Variant

 ' First Switch Off Display Alerts
   daWas = Application.DisplayAlerts
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
 ' Done

 ' Open & Check the Database Workbook
   Set dBook = Workbooks.Open("YourDatabaseWorkbook.xlsm")
   If dBook.ReadOnly Then
      dBook.Close False
      MsgBox "Database in Use - Retry Later"
   Else
      ' Write to dBook, Save & Close it
   End If
 ' Done

 ' RESET DisplayAlerts
   Application.DisplayAlerts = daWas
 ' Done
```

Comment: Can you guide me a bit more on this? How to check its ReadOnly property? I could only find tutorial on setting the property to read only

Comment: I don't get how this would work, if the user has to download the file to set it to readonly and then re-save it while he does changes to it, then resave it again, then doesn't that leave the same window open as it would for if two users tried to download and save changes to it anyway? And if you can open it directly from the network then why not just check if it's open to prevent an overwrite save?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on a few things but you could lose data. One mechanism I've used in the past where people wanted to download files is implement a checkout system - this pseudo-code which you could have in the distributed UserForm file:

```
Sub DownloadAndSave()
' In the location in the network folder:
' If a file exists called "MyData_CHECKOUT.xlsm" then
      'deny a save
' Else
      ' RENAME the target file to "MyData_CHECKOUT.xlsm"
' Download "MyData_CHEKOUT.xlsm", make changes, save file to network as "MyData.xlsm"
' Delete the MyData_CHECKOUT.xlsm" file
End Sub
```

Although if people have access to the network drive, can they not just OPEN the file directly to make changes (instead of downloading, changing and resaving) - you can then use this code to check if the book is already open, to deny changes being made at the same time:

```
Function IsWorkBookOpen(FileName As String) as Boolean
Dim ff As Long, ErrNo As Long

On Error Resume Next
ff = FreeFile()
Open FileName For Input Lock Read As #ff
Close ff
ErrNo = Err
On Error GoTo 0

Select Case ErrNo
Case 0:    IsWorkBookOpen = False
Case 70:   IsWorkBookOpen = True
Case Else: Error ErrNo
End Select
End Function
```

Comment: The database file will be read-only and it will only be editable through the form

Comment: I like your 1st solution, I will try and implement that and see